# ¿Cómo extraer día, mes, año en R?

Tags: r

Estoy teniendo una prolemilla para extraer día, mes y año del campo date en R. El siguiente es mi dataset:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve tratando de hacer de la siguiente manera, pero me arroja todo NA:

```
mi_fecha <- strptime(datos$date, tz='UTC', format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y")
library(lubridate)
day(mi_fecha)
```

Espero vuestro ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo cambiando la configuración regional, y es como sigue:

```
#Extraer la configuración actual
original_locale = Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")

#Cambiar a formato 'English'
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "English")

#Transformar la fecha
mi_fecha = strptime(datos$date, tz='UTC', format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y")
library(lubridate)
day(mi_fecha)

#Cambiar de vuelta a la configuración inicial
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = original_locale)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar lubridate para la conversion. Quizas te falto la `a` para denominar el dia de la semana (a = nombre del dia, m = mes, d = dia) al intentarlo.

```
library(lubridate)
fecha <- "Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009"
mi_fecha <- parse_date_time(fecha, orders = "amd HMS y")
day(mi_fecha)
```

te dara `11` como resultado y `month(mi_fecha)` y `year(mi_fecha)` los otros componentes que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función format() sobre el objeto "yearmon" ejemplo:

`date1 <- as.yearmon("Mar 2012", "%b %Y")`

Luego puedes extraer las partes de la fecha requeridas:

```
> format(date1, "%b") ## Mes, char, abreviado
[1] "Mar"
> format(date1, "%Y") ## Año
[1] "2012"
> format(date1, "%m") ## Mes numérico
[1] "03"
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749598/extract-month-and-year-from-a-zooyearmon-object